# SQL recursive records: How can I collapse to 'one level only'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, recursion, firebird

I have records with a project id and an 'inherit id', i.e. the project that the current project inherits from. The inheritance level is unknown.

I now need to collapse this to: 'inherit from the top most'

E.g.:

```
1006 <- 1005 <- 1002 <- 999
```

prj_id / inherit_id

```
999  / 1002

1002 / 1005

1005 / 1006
```

should collapse to

```
1006 <- 1005 

1006 <- 1002

1006 <- 999
```

prj_id / inherit_id

```
999  / 1006

1002 / 1006

1005 / 1006
```

Can this be done in SQL statement without loops?
Creating temporary tables is fine.
It should work for FireBird, SQL Server, Oracle 9+ (i.e. 3 sets of statements is fine)

I only got this far:

Records that inherit from a record that itself inherits again:

```
select tt_prj_id,tt_name,tt_inherit_id from tt_prj a

where a.tt_inherit_id in

(select tt_prj_id from tt_prj b

 where b.tt_inherit_id is not null

 and b.tt_inherit_id > 0)
```

Who can help me further?

Comment: As far as I know, Oracle is the only engine that supports [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) natively.

Comment: In MYSQL you can use the group_concat function too.

Comment: what do "root" projects have as inherit_id ?

Comment: @alex: they will just have inherit_id is null

Comment: There is an additional complication: the user may have created circular references in the past ;-(

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Hierarchical queries are supported by Oracle, DB2, Firebird (since 2.5), PostgreSQL (since 8.4), Teradata, SQL Server and Sybase. Read up on "recursive common table expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following should get you started (it's not the final solution!):

```
with recursive project_tree as (
   select tt_prj_id, cast(tt_prj_id as varchar(500))||'/' as id_path, tt_prj_id as root_id
   from tt_prj
   where tt_inherit_id = 0

   union all

   select c.tt_prj_id, id_path || cast(c.tt_prj_id as varchar(100)) ||'/', null
   from tt_prj c
     join project_tree p on c.tt_inherit_id = p.tt_prj_id
)
select *
from project_tree;
```

This works Firebird 2.5 (might also work with 2.1, but I don't have one at hand right now)

It should work with SQL Server when you remove the keyword `recursive` (which is required by the ANSI standard, but since when did Microsoft care about that...) and you need to replace the standard string concatention `||` with the `+` operator.

Oracle does only support recursive CTEs before 11.2.
In prior version you need to rewrite this using `CONNECT BY`, which woudl be something like this:

```
select tt_prj_id, tt_inherit_id, sys_connect_by_path(tt_prj_id, '/')
from tt_prj
start with tt_inherit_id = 0
connect by prior tt_prj_id = tt_inherit_id;
```

Comment: i think '||' has to be replaced by '+' for the code to work in tsql (half a question, half a comment here ... never seen that operator in tsql before)

Comment: @Alex: correct I always forget that Microsoft violates the SQL rules there as well.

Comment: Is there some reason you're concatenating?  If all you're going for is the 'root' node and the 'current' one, root can simply be propogated.

Comment: @X-Zero With the concatenation you can see the full path of the tree. That's the only reason. I think it helps understanding the output especially for someone who is new to recursive queries

Comment: Thanks all, this should get me going!

Answer (score 1):

Do a search on `transitive closure tables` or `nested sets`. Their structures make it possible to efficiently query relational data, but it takes more maintenance on inserts/updates/deletes, and the closure tables will require storing additional records (trade-off space for efficiency).

Comment: Thanks Sam, but there's no need to have a proper nested DB structure in the app. This is just a one-time update script for one table to be run on the current data structure. The next app version will only allow one inheritance.

Comment: OK. Not sure how you are going to take a table with `n` levels of relationships and write the SQL without loops then...

Answer (score 1):

User a_horse_with_no_name is correct.  This operation can be performed with recursive CTEs.  Check out this link for more info.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/

Once again, Pinal Dave ftw.